# Imagens não ficam dentro da div

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Tenho uma div aonde quero deixar dentro dela 2 imagens uma em cima da outra, e somente a imagem checada em um input ficará visível, enquanto a legenda da imagem visível deve se posicionar a direita da imagem. Porém, estou tentando deixar a div container com `position:relative;` e as imagens com `position:absolute`, para que as imagens fiquem absolute em relação a div, mas não estou conseguindo. as imagens "fogem" da div, a div fica sem nada dentro e o conteúdo fica logo abaixo.

Eis o que eu tenho: https://jsfiddle.net/rckecf2b/1/

Poderiam me ajudar ?

Comment: Obrigado @MarllonNasser ! =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transformei o comentário em resposta:

Coloque `height: 200px;` na declaração do css `#container-fim-ap`, veja: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rckecf2b/2)

Comment: Obrigado ! ajudou demais !